# Evaluation float('inf') times symbolic variable with Python

Tags: python, sympy

I need integrate `exp(-c1*r)`, with respect to `'r'` that goes from 0 to infinity, where `'c1'` and `'r'` are symbols.

The problem seems to occur when evaluate `inf*c1` not equal to `inf`

```
import sympy
from sympy import *

# Defining the variable 
c1 = Symbol('c1', positive=True)
r =  Symbol('r')

print float('inf')*2
print float('inf')*c1
print integrate(exp(-c1*r),(r,0,10000))
print integrate(exp(-c1*r),(r,0,float('inf')))
```

How to make that `-inf*c1 = -inf`?

Comment: That's rigth, but when you do inf*c1 not return inf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `sympy.oo`, which is Sympy's symbol for infinity. Try:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy


sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX like pretty printing for IPython

r = sy.Symbol('r', real=True)
c1 = sy.Symbol('c_1', positive=True)

f = sy.exp(-c1*r)
F = sy.integrate(f, (r, 0, sy.oo))
display(F)
```